# DD-WRT Connection Leak

Tags: connection, dd-wrt

I have DD-WRT installed on a WRT54G v1.1, and a few of the features seem to cause connections to leak. I've configured it for 1024 connections with TCP/UDP timeouts of 180/30. I've tried higher values as well. Anyway, if I use the Bandwidth tab to monitor the bandwidth usage, the number of connections to my workstation reaches about 450. Is this normal? If not, any idea how to get the connections to either not be created, or to drop much faster?

Comment: Are you experiencing a particular problem, or are you just observing a number which you think it too high?

Comment: If I hadn't raised my connection limit, it would have used up all the connections. Also, the load on the router CPU gets extremely high, degrading performance in some cases. Regardless of that though, it shouldn't require that many connections to monitor bandwidth usage.

Comment: Which build are you using? Have you looked in dd-wrt's forum for wrt54g?